# Finding an orthornormal basis given a bilinear form

Tags: normed-spaces

Take $ \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form (which may not be positive definite). Take $\Vert x\Vert = \vert \langle x,x\rangle \vert^{1/2}$. I want to show that there is an orthonormal basis.

My problem: Because $ \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is nondegenerate, there is a $y$ for which $ \langle x,y\rangle \not=0$. However, it may be the case that $\Vert x\Vert=0 $ for all $x$, so that I cannot use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: non degenerate still implies that $\| x\| =0 \iff x=0$